# What's the connection between the pole contours of propagators and their causality?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, special-relativity, greens-functions, correlation-functions, propagator

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propagator#Feynman_propagator) distinguishes between three kinds of propagators for a scalar field:

- The **Retarded propagator's** contours have $\mathrm{Im}(k^0)>0$ on both poles, so its limit is completely in the first and second quadrants.
- The **Advanced propagator's** contours have $\mathrm{Im}(k^0)<0$ on both poles, so its limit is completely in the third and fourth quadrants.
- The **Feynman propagator's** contour has $\mathrm{Im}(k^0)<0$ at the $k_0=-\sqrt{\vec{k}^2+m^2}$ pole and $\mathrm{Im}(k^0)>0$ at the $k_0=+\sqrt{\vec{k}^2+m^2}$ pole, so its limit lies completely in the first and third quadrant.

What's the relation between the choice of contours and the causality/light cones of the propagators? In other words, why are the first two propagators *retarded* and *advanced*, and what's their connection to the time-ordered operator product?